# How to sort python Sqlite database in Ascending order based on a particular column?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sorting

I have python-3.7 and also sqlite module.

If I want to sort the rows according to ascending order of a particular column how do I do it?

All the columns contain strings. I want to sort the database according to 'name' column's strings' ascending order?

```py
def sort():
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('SQLite_Python.db');
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor();
        print("Connected to SQLite");

        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT * FROM 'SqliteDb_Addresser'
                        ORDER BY ('name') ASC;""";

        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query);
        print("SQLite DB is sorted in ascending order succesfully.");

        cursor.close();

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert Python variable into sqlite table", error);
    finally:
        if (sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close();
            print("The SQLite connection is closed");
```

Comment: Remove the quotes around `name`.

Comment: you don't need semicolons to end statements in python unless you're using multiple statements in a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM SqliteDb_Addresser ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE ASC`

This ignores letter case